# Is there a way to have breakpoints in css grid without using the repeat() function?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

What I want is a grid, where at full size there is a div that takes up 2fr and another that takes up 1fr. Each has a minimum size, and when the minimum size is reached when the window is resized, I want the second div to break beneath.

```
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: minmax(1000px, 2fr) repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px, 1fr));">
<div>
    Div 1
</div>

<div>
    Div 2
</div>
```

I was hoping that using auto-fit in the repeat function would do what I want, but the code above does the same as using `grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;`

If I do `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px, 1fr));`, I get almost what I want except the two divs are always the same size.

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible, but it seems like you're trying to use repeat to set non repeating values.

Comment: RAM (repeat auto minmax) is not works with minmax() in other columns

Comment: this is what flexbox is made for

Answer (score -2):

Use Media Query for specific breakpoint, if breakpoint reaches then make your div display block with max-width assigned so that div width remains as your requirement.